# Use wmemset initialize cause coredump

Tags: c++

I want to convert an `int` value to `wchar_t buffer[MAX_LEN]`,use `std::to_wstring(dwValue);` then use `res.copy`  copy the value to buffer,I don't know why cause a coredump.If I del the `wmemset` line ,everything goes well.

I use `gdb` and `valgrind` and  find no reason. Here is `valgrind` result:

```
==30757== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==30757==    at 0x0: ???
==30757==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==30757== 
==30757== 
==30757== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==30757==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==30757==    at 0x0: ???
==30757== 
==30757== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30757==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30757==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 44 bytes allocated
==30757== 
==30757== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30757== 
==30757== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30757== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

My code below:

```
/* intTowstring example */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cwchar>

std::wstring intToWstring( int dwValue )
{
    std::wstring str = L"";

    str = std::to_wstring(dwValue);
    return str;
}

int main ()
{

     wchar_t buffer[128];
     wmemset (buffer,L'\0',sizeof(wchar_t) * 128);

     int flags = 2048;

     std::wstring res = intToWstring(flags);
     res.copy(buffer,res.size(),0);

     wprintf(L"%ls\n",buffer);

     return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: wow, it shows on my system, `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated`.  `＼(^o^)／`

Comment: thanks Davide Spataro to edit the question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wmemset (buffer,L'\0',sizeof(wchar_t) * 128);
```

This I guess is wrong. From [`wmemset` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wmemset):

> **`count`** - number of wide characters to fill

You are providing a number of bytes instead. Change to:

```
wmemset (buffer,L'\0',128);
```

Comment: I will try later ,but [wmemset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wmemset/?kw=wmemset)  say :Number of bytes to be set to the value.
size_t is an unsigned integral type.

Comment: @52coder Interesting, cppreference says number of characters.

Comment: @52coder It seems that cplusplus.com is wrong here. C Standard also says _the number of characters_: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.29.4.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the documentation of `wmemset`  is telling you that the last parameter should be the **number of elements** and not the number of bytes.

Quoting from the documentation:

```
wchar_t* wmemset( wchar_t* dest, wchar_t ch, std::size_t count );

Parameters
dest    -   pointer to the wide character array to fill
ch  -   fill wide character
count   -   number of wide characters to fill
```

**The Solution is** to change the call to `wmemset` to `wmemset (buffer,L'\0',128);`

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wmemset)

Comment: thanks,I read this,then got wrong use.[wmemset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wmemset/?kw=wmemset)